# Simulate keyboard event not working on textarea in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to simulate keyboard events, more specifically the arrows events, in a textarea used as a terminal. I treat keyboard event separately to reproduce what would happen in a real terminal.

I have tried a couple of methods I found online but none of them seems to work for my case.

HTML

```
<textarea
   id="terminal"
   autocorrect="off"
   spellcheck="false"
   @click.prevent
   @keydown.prevent="handleKey"
></textarea>
```

JS

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleKey(event) {
      // some checks on other keyboard events...

      if (event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) {
        const element = document.getElementById('terminal')
        this.fireKey(element, event.key)
      }

      // Checks continue...
    }
    fireKey(element, key) {
      if (!element) {
        return
      }
      const keydown = document.createEvent('Events')
      keydown.initEvent('keydown', true, true)
      keydown.keyCode = keydown.which = key
      element.dispatchEvent(keydown)

      var keyup = document.createEvent('Events')
      keyup.initEvent('keyup', true, true)
      keyup.keyCode = keyup.which = key
      console.info(keyup)
      element.dispatchEvent(keyup)
    },

  }
}
</script>
```

I also tried

```
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key }))
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key }))
```

instead `document.createEvent` but it did not work either.

I expect the events to be fired but instead nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try `@input`? :D

Comment: first of all you missed , between your methods. second dont use it like this `@keydown.prevent="handleKey"` just use `@keydown="handleKey"` and in your handleKey method call `event.stopPropagation()`. Works for me. when you use it like `@keydown.prevent="handleKey"` you actually block the user input (unless you will manuly handle it)

Comment: thanks @elichen ! The missing comma was just a copy-paste mistake. I can't believe I didn't even think of `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: I posted it as answer.

Comment: Well this is more a workaround than an answer to why the dispatchEvent does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
<textarea
   id="terminal"
   autocorrect="off"
   spellcheck="false"
   @click.prevent
   @keydown.prevent="handleKey"
></textarea>
```

To  the following. so you dont block the input or you will have to handle it manualy

```
<textarea
   id="terminal"
   autocorrect="off"
   spellcheck="false"
   @click.prevent
   @keydown="handleKey"
></textarea>
```

And in the event handler prevent it (stop the propagation) by call. In this case

```
handleKey(event) {
...
event.stopPropagation()
}
```